# In RxJS is it possible to test for pending values in an auditTime() operation?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm using RxJS's `.auditTime(500)` operation ([docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-auditTime)) as a trailing throttle: I want to emit a server call at most once every 500 ms.

Downstream when the server call completes I need to inquire whether there are more pending server calls or if the buffer is clear for now so that I can communicate this information to users in the form of status messages like "Saving…" and "Saved".

Here's roughly what that looks like.

```
saveToServerObservable
  .do(() => {
    // gets called every time
    setStatus(Status.SAVING);
  })
  .auditTime(500) // wait 500 ms and emit no more than once per 500 ms
  .flatMap(data => axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "/saveurl",
    data: data,
  }))
  .map(response => response.data)
  .do(data => {
    // here I want to know whether there are pending values from the
    // auditTime() operation above or if the buffer is currently clear
    const pendingSaves = ???;
    if (!pendingSaves) {
     setStatus(Status.SAVED);
    }
  })
  .subscribe();
```

As you can see in the final `.do()` operation, I want to know whether there are pending values from the `.auditTime(500)` operation. How can I achieve something like this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incrementing and decrementing a counter was too susceptible to bugs, so I ended up going with a wholly different approach. I now separately track whether the local data is "dirty." I use this dirty signal to show a "Saving…" vs "Saved" message to the user:

1. Every time the user makes a local edit, I locally update the data and set `dirty` to `true`.
2. After each save operation, the server responds with the latest version of the data it has.
3. Upon receiving that response, I diff the local version of the data with what gets returned by the server, and if they match I set `dirty` to `false`.

## Setting `dirty` to `true` on each edit

Here I define an `Rx.Subject` for each time the user makes an edit. Each time it receives a signal, I set `dirty` to `true`.

```js
// stream of signals to save the active document
const userEditSignal$ = new Rx.Subject();

const savePrototype = () => {
  userEditSignal$.next();
};

userEditSignal$.subscribe(() => {
  // runs for each call to save the active document
  store.commit("SET_DIRTY", true);
});
```

## Observe the `dirty` state to decide when to save to server

This lets us know every time the `dirty` value changes, which is not the same as every time it is set.

```js
const observeState = (store, getter) => {
  // irrelevant details redacted
}

// emits only when `dirty` changes, not every time it's set
const shouldSaveToServer$ = observeState(store, state => state.dirty);
```

## Create a stream of request objects and server responses

This custom timing logic replaces the need for the `auditTime()` operator.

```js
const saveToServerSignal$ = shouldSaveToServer$.switchMap(shouldSave => {
  return shouldSave ?
    // as long as we should save, save every 500 ms
    Rx.Observable.interval(500) :
    // when we should not, stop
    Rx.Observable.never();
});

// create a request object for each save-to-server signal
const saveRequest$ = saveToServerSignal$
  .mapTo(store.state.activeDocument)
  .map(createSaveRequest);

// 
const saveResponse$ = saveRequest$
  // sends immediately
  .flatMap(request => axios(request));
```

## On every response, check diff the local document and the version returned from the server

If they agree, we can set `dirty` to `false`.

```js
saveResponse$
  .map(response => response.data)
  .do(savedDocument => {
    const activeDocument = store.state.activeDocument;

    // update just `created`, `modified`, and `user`
    store.commit({
      type: "UPDATE_ACTIVE_DOCUMENT",
      // irrelevant details omitted
    });

    // diff current state and saved document (function details omitted)
    const activeAndSavedDocsMatch = diff(activeDocument, savedDocument);
    if (activeAndSavedDocsMatch) {
      store.commit("SET_DIRTY", false);
    }
  })
  .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could achieve what you want using `scan` and by slightly modifying your chain:

```
const inc = new Subject();
const dec = new Subject();

const counter = Observable.merge(dec.mapTo(-1), inc.throttleTime(500).mapTo(1))
    .scan((acc, val) => acc + val, 0)
    .map(val => val > 0);

saveToServerObservable
  .do(() => {
    // gets called every time
    setStatus(Status.SAVING);
    inc.next();
  })
  .auditTime(500) // wait 500 ms and emit no more than once per 500 ms
  .flatMap(data => axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "/saveurl",
    data: data,
  }))
  .do(() => dec.next())
  .map(response => response.data)
  .withLatestFrom(counter, (data, pendingSaves) => {
    if (!pendingSaves) {
     setStatus(Status.SAVED);
    }
  })
  .subscribe();
```

The whole idea is in the `counter` Observable that merges `inc` and `dec`. These two Observables increment and decrement a counter using `scan()`.

The `inc` is also chained with `.throttleTime(500)` to make the exact opposite of `.auditTime(500)` because when you call `setStatus(Status.SAVING);` you always know this will make `.auditTime(500)` emit an item, therefore you can increment the counter right away.

Then `withLatestFrom` just merges the counter with the result of the remote call and that's the place where you can check what was the latest emission from `counter`.

Comment: Works beautifully, @martin. Thank you. 